# operador ternário dentro de função

Tags: javascript

bom pessoal fiz um pequeno código, que ele verifica se a string `ending` é igual ao final da  string `word`, até aí tudo certo porém eu quis usar operador ternário para deixar o código mais compacto, e ele ficou assim.

```
let word = 'carslefajenando'
let ending = 'nando'
let endword;

function finalEqual() {
    ending.length > word.length ? false : true
    endword = word.slice(word.length - ending.length, word.length)
    (endword == ending) ? true : false
}

console.log(finalEqual())
```

porém ele retorna undefined. se eu coloco o segundo if com o if normal ele funciona, creio que seja a forma que estou usando o operador ternário, gostaria de entender em que estou errando

Answer (score -1):

Você precisa retornar o valor que está sendo verificado no operador ternário.

```
let word = 'carslefajenando'
let ending = 'nando'
let endword;

function finalEqual() {
    // essa expressão também não está sendo usada em nenhum lugar, é totalmente descartável
    ending.length > word.length ? false : true 

    endword = word.slice(word.length - ending.length, word.length)
    return (endword == ending) ? true : false
}

console.log(finalEqual())
```

Outra coisa: ternários que resultam em `true` ou `false` são redudantes, você pode simplesmente omitir a verificação e retornar o valor da condicional.

```js
return endword == ending
```